# Por que os jornalistas utilizam o tempo presente em matérias jornalísticas?

Tags: verbos, tempo-verbal

Recentemente, ao ler algumas notícias, percebi que alguns jornais utilizam o verbo no presente do indicativo, o que não ocorre no subtítulo e corpo da matéria.

> Dois índios Guajajara **morrem** e dois **ficam** feridos durante atentado no Maranhão

> Justiça **determina** soltura de suspeita

> Brasileiro **é** alvo de racismo em clássico de Manchester

- Há uma regra na norma culta que permita isso?
- O uso segue a regra do *presente histórico* usado nos livros de história? Se não, qual a diferença?
- Noutros países lusófonos, é comum utilizarem esse artifício?

Comment: Sim, seria o mesmo presente histórico. Na escola se ensina que ele é usado para trazer os fatos narrados para mais próximo do leitor e simplificar a linguagem (evitando a necessidade de construções mais complexas como o pretérito mais-que-perfeito).

Comment: Há alguns anos, a capa de uma revista noticiava: "morre o Papa".

Answer (score 1):

Hoje li o jornal tendo em mente este post.

Fiquei com a impressão que na primeira página todas as notícias são escritas no `presente histórico`...Enquanto no resto do jornal o predominante é o pretérito passado. (Tal opção não será por acaso.)

Gostei deste artigo sobre o [presente histórico](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-presente-historico-ou-narrativo/15381).

> Noutros países lusófonos, é comum utilizarem esse artifício?

Em Portugal sim, pelo menos na primeira página dos jornais...

Answer (score 0):

**Costume** não contém *norma culta*, portanto, a licença poética abusada por jornalistas adultera a eficácia da significação. Sempre que a frase gerar compreensão dúbia, ela tem pobreza de norma culta.